# Search for multiple patterns inside a pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm using regular expressions to extract data from a website, but now I found a problem.

This is part of the original HTML that I want to parse. I want to extract the text after "descuentos-" and the city, after the "<a href>".

```
<div id="cities2_2">
  <a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-espana/">Badajoz</a>
  <a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-espana/">Badalona</a>
  <a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-barcelona/">Barcelona</a>
  <a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-bilbao/">Bilbao</a>
  <a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-espana/">Burgos</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="capa_cities" onmouseover="act_formato(3, 2);"
     onmouseout="desact_formato(3, 2);">
<h2 id="title_city3_2">C</h2>
<div id="cities3_2">
  <a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-espana/">Cáceres</a>
  <a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-cadiz/">Cádiz</a>
  <a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-espana/">Cartagena</a>
  <a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-espana/">Castellón</a>
  <a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-espana/">Ceuta</a>
  <a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-espana/">Ciudad Real</a>
  <a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-cordoba/">Córdoba</a>
  <a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-espana/">Cuenca</a>
```

I could look for <a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-(.*)">, but there are others that match the pattern in the website. So I now have this pattern:

```
#<div id="cities[0-9]+_2">(<a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-(.*?)/">(.*?)</a>)*#
```

I'd like to have it recursive. I mean: for each "<a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-(.* )/">(.*)</a>" found, search for the two small patterns inside.

Is there a way to achieve this in regex, or I have to reprocess it through preg_match_all?

Comment: Did you consider using an html parser?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. Use a HTML-parser.

Comment: For other easier chunks, like the most I'll be extracting, I thought it would be overkill. For this in particular, yes, but I'd prefer to use the same everywhere.

Comment: What would you like to search for, after you get the matches?

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos I don't understand what you are asking for. I need the small patterns only.

Comment: You say you want it to be recursive. I thought you wanted to search again after you find the match you want.

Comment: What I want is to get the a href matches, and for each match, look for the small patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 : quick way: Yes, use preg_match_all()

```
preg_match_all('#<a href = "http://website.com/descuentos-(.*?)/">.*?</a>#', $str, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Badajoz
            [1] => Badalona
            [2] => Barcelona
            [3] => Bilbao
            [4] => Burgos
            [5] => Cáceres
            [6] => Cádiz
            [7] => Cartagena
            [8] => Castellón
            [9] => Ceuta
            [10] => Ciudad Real
            [11] => Córdoba
            [12] => Cuenca
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => espana
            [1] => espana
            [2] => barcelona
            [3] => bilbao
            [4] => espana
            [5] => espana
            [6] => cadiz
            [7] => espana
            [8] => espana
            [9] => espana
            [10] => espana
            [11] => cordoba
            [12] => espana
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Badajoz
            [1] => Badalona
            [2] => Barcelona
            [3] => Bilbao
            [4] => Burgos
            [5] => Cáceres
            [6] => Cádiz
            [7] => Cartagena
            [8] => Castellón
            [9] => Ceuta
            [10] => Ciudad Real
            [11] => Córdoba
            [12] => Cuenca
        )

)

Time elapsed: 0.000104904174805
```

---

Option 2:
**DOM Parser**:
($str is your text);

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($links as $link){
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');

    echo $href." ### ";//prints the href
    preg_match('#descuentos-(.*)/#', $href, $match);
    echo $link->nodeValue." - ".$match[1]."<br/>";
}
```

Output (add the utf-8 headers to see the correct chars):

```
http://website.com/descuentos-espana/ ### Badajoz - espana
http://website.com/descuentos-espana/ ### Badalona - espana
http://website.com/descuentos-barcelona/ ### Barcelona - barcelona
http://website.com/descuentos-bilbao/ ### Bilbao - bilbao
http://website.com/descuentos-espana/ ### Burgos - espana
http://website.com/descuentos-espana/ ### CÃ¡ceres - espana
http://website.com/descuentos-cadiz/ ### CÃ¡diz - cadiz
http://website.com/descuentos-espana/ ### Cartagena - espana
http://website.com/descuentos-espana/ ### CastellÃ³n - espana
http://website.com/descuentos-espana/ ### Ceuta - espana
http://website.com/descuentos-espana/ ### Ciudad Real - espana
http://website.com/descuentos-cordoba/ ### CÃ³rdoba - cordoba
http://website.com/descuentos-espana/ ### Cuenca - espana
Time elapsed: 0.000319004058838
```

Comment: Talking about regex, I cannot use the "a href" form because there are other coincident things that are not what I need, that's why I have to search for the parent tag and do a bit of recursion. About parser, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Then it's a reason more to use the DOM Parser definetively, if all those tags are inside a element with a specific class or id, you cant target that element easily with getElementById() or getElementByClassName(), to get its children and loop through them forgetting about the pieces of html you don't want from the document